# What's the best way to transfer an OAuth token from the backend to the front-end in an API-based approach?

Tags: javascript, oauth, passport.js

Here are my steps:

1. From the front-end, I redirect users to an endpoint of my API, which then redirects them to the respective Google/Facebook/Github login page.
2. After users log in on their social page, a callback API in my backend is triggered.
3. Now after the callback called In the backend, I have access to user information like email, picture, and other details.
4. Using this information, I generate a token using JWT.
5. Finally, I redirect users back to my front-end using `res.redirect(FRONT_END_URL)`.

My question is, how can I securely send the access token to the front-end from the backend after the token is generated? So that i can store it in front-end localstorage

Comment: There are so many questions and answers about how to send JWT from backend to front end. No matter what language and framework you are using.

Answer (score 2):

saving JWT token in local storage is not safe because the Client has access to the token (XSS attack).

use cookies and CSRF token can be safe way. i mean save your JWT token in cookie and use CSRF token in header.

Comment: Okay, My question is actully how can I pass the token from the backend to front-end? So that i can store it on cookies or localstorage

Comment: in frontend when you send first request to backend(login) you get jwt token in response of your login and before send your next request to backend you have to set jwtToken in header of your request in Authorization.('Bearer'+res.data['token']) if you want set your JWT token in cookie when you get your token in backend you can set jwt token in cookie. then when you set cookie in your backend in all of your Request you have JWT Token in your cookie and can get response in all of request. and don't forget set configure of CSRF token by some anotation check validiation of csrf token in backend.

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question, the question was related to OAuth, not regular login. In OAuth, user information is obtained when receiving a callback from social platforms (Google, Facebook.)

Comment: dear user read your question you used JWT Token if you use JWT token for you authenticate you have to set your token in header of your request to be authenticate for backend and according to your question you asked: 'My question is, how can I securely transfer the access token to the front-end? So that i can store it in front-end localstorage' and answer is clear saving token in local storage is not safe and i explained you about secure transfer between backend and front. i think you need to study more about JWT mechanism in front end and backend good luck

Comment: I don't think this question is about JWT, In the questions description flow steps 4 and 5, if you focus on those steps and the title, you can see that I was seeking an answer on how to transfer the generated token to the front-end. One option I can think of is passing it in query parameters

Comment: your application is Rest Api or what ?

Comment: Yes, it's Rest API

Comment: so you can get your response in json by sending any request to backend whats your front end ?

Comment: This is a different scenario. It's all related to OAuth. Please read this question